# 2-d array numpy array row column index comparison

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

What would be the python numpy equivalent of the  c++ code given below in the link? I am a beginner in python and was getting confused on how to change this code to python.Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html).

```
np.fill_diagonal(a,10)
```